# When called ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) in OnClose method has painting issues MFC

Tags: mfc

I've created a Modaless dialog inside a dialog A which displays some content. I've overridden ONClose() event of Modalless dialog and hidden the modaless dialog inside it and sends the message to dialog A to load the content again. Now the problem is whenever I've launched the modaless dialog and moved that dialog inside the main dialog and then closed the dialog. The portion of the dialog displayed inside the dialog A is not re-painted.

In Debugging I found that Dialog A is actually painted after modaless dialog got closed in the client area of Dialog A and then after the On Close Event done in Modaless dialog, the portion of the modaless dialog which has painted is lost and that portion is background as white( I've handled EraseBackgroung to white).

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Some code and a picture are worth a thousand words.

Comment: Can you not just call `::InvalidateRect()` on the window not being repainted?

Comment: Why OnPaint is not trigerred after ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)? Here is my piece of code... void CCModelelssDlg::OnClose() { ShowWindow(SW_HIDE); // Here is where Invalidate region occurred after dialog is hidden. LoadContent();}